# Per axis grid properties (color), how it works?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, 3d, qt5

From this source code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <Q3DScatter>

using namespace QtDataVisualization;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    Q3DScatter *graph = new Q3DScatter;
    QWidget *widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(graph);
    setCentralWidget(widget);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {}
```

I get:

[image]

See that wall directly in front, its grayed (can I describe it this way?) if compared to the other walls. How can I tweak grid lines that way? I mean just one wall.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you can change the color of the grid-line with the following code.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtDataVisualization/Q3DScatter>
#include <QtDataVisualization/Q3DLight>
#include <QtDataVisualization/Q3DTheme>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    auto scatter = new QtDataVisualization::Q3DScatter;
    auto widget=QWidget::createWindowContainer(scatter);
    widget->show();
    scatter->activeTheme()->setType(QtDataVisualization::Q3DTheme::ThemeQt);
    scatter->activeTheme()->setGridLineColor(QColor("red"));
    auto light = scatter->scene()->activeLight();
    auto camera = scatter->scene()->activeCamera();
    int counter = 0;
    QTimer timer;
    timer.start(1 / 60);
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&]() {
        camera->setXRotation(counter++/60);
    });
    return a.exec();
}
```

Still, there seems to be no effect on how the grid-lines are rendered. I think this is do to the lighting of the 3D scene and of course of the camera position.

My small example program rotates the camera of the scene and therefore also the lighting of the grid-lines changes.

I think, there is little you can do here, as the interfaces doesn't allow you to change the shader code of the grid-lines.

Comment: Maybe you can use QCustomplot or similar libraries. If 3d is not a necessity there are many potential replacement.

Comment: 3D is a necessity.

Comment: Maybe you can try https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp. Just browse the internet. Also consider, what is really important and what is just nice to have.

Comment: Sure, already quick checked matplotlib-cpp however I'm still considering a Qt approach.

Answer (score 0):

Solution might be to add a custom 3d item, set a mesh and texture color. Resize the item to look like a grid axis and set the position. Repeat the idea for as many axis lines it is required.

Wondering if there is a (better) alternative approach.